# Initializing member variables with a lambda

Tags: c++, constructor

Suppose I have a template class:

```
template<class T>
class Entity
{
public:
  Entity(std::function<void(T*)> init, int idx) : index(idx)
  {
    init(data);
  }

  T* getData(){ return Data; }

private:
  int index;
  T* data;
};
```

And I create an instance of the class as so:

```
Entity<Button> myEnt([](Button* button){
  button = new Button();

  /* some complex, **unique**, initialization of button */

  }, 1);
```

This will compile, but when I call `getData()` and attempt to use the pointer returned in some other function the program crashes. I assume its because there is an error where `data` doesn't get properly initialized, but I cant tell why!

fwiw I can get the program to run as desired if I change the `Entity` constructor to:

```
Entity(std::function<T*(void)> init, int idx) : index(idx)
{
  data = init();
}
```

and then call it as so:

```
Entity<Button> myEnt([](){
  Button* button = new Button();

  /* some complex, **unique**, initialization of button */

  return button;
  }, 1);
```

But in my opinion that's an undesirable way of doing it, and the first method should work, im just missing something.

Comment: Don't you mean `data(init);` instead of `init(data);`? Also, why aren't you initializing it in a member initializer list?

Comment: I suppose `data(init)` works too. The reason i'm doing things by passing a lambda to the constructor is because each time the class is instantiated, it will be initialized in a different way, e.g an `Entity<Button>` gets initialized differently to an `Entity<Slider>` , which gets initialized differently to an `Entity<Label>`  etc. Therefore i put the unique initialization in a lambda and pass it to the constructor to execute.

Comment: Your lambda needs to take the pointer by reference if you intend to use the lambda to initialize the parameter.

Comment: The second way you illustrate (where the pointer is returned) is a more idiomatic way to acquire newly allocated objects, and can be used with member initialization rather than being in the body.

Comment: Do you really need a pointer at all here. Why not store the object by value in your entity class? If you need the pointer, you should use a smart pointer.

Comment: @jxh in that sense, would you say its more optimal? it would seem it requires more resource allocation, creating a new `Button` object as opposed to taking a reference to the one which already exists as a member of `Entity` ?

Comment: @super In reality I am using Qt, and it doesnt really play nicely with smart pointers. Instead they like to pass around objects as raw pointers ... I would have used smart pointers if possible.

Comment: `Entity<Button>`, `Entity<Slider>` and `Entity<Label>` all have their own constructor that can do things differently (you can specialize), you do not necessarily need this lambda trick.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I dont understand, could you point me to a reference or explain a little more what you mean by '(you can specialize)' . Thanks

Comment: simple example: https://godbolt.org/z/G86axb To me it looks like you are mixing compile time (templates) and runtime (passing a lambda) when you need only one of the two.

Comment: @idclev463035818 that is a great alternative actually, yes! Thanks. The only constraint is that using a lambda you can kinda write the constructors on the fly, but actually your methods works better for my needs.

Comment: note that there are no template classes. `Entity` is not a class. It is just a template from which you can instantiate different classes. Thats more or less what I meant when I wrote "they have their own constructor". `Entity<Button>` is a type distinct from `Entity<Slider>`, they have nothing in common (other than being two instantiations of the same class template)

Comment: A function (or lambda) parameter is equivalent to a variable local to the function but is already initialized at the time the function is called. You aren't really saving anything in the sense that you mean it.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Ah, I failed to make that realization. But suppose I wanted to pass a variadic number of parametes to the instantiated constructor( like so https://godbolt.org/z/fjs9T4 ) then how would that be resolved?

Comment: that could make another question, but here you go: https://godbolt.org/z/KWM6h1

Comment: @idclev463035818 apologies for so may questions, you had me curious. You've helped me a lot, thanks.

Comment: no need to aplogize, I just think it would be nicer to have those as proper questions with proper answer rather than only in comments, but thats my fault not yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `data` to `init()` *by value*, which means the lambda is receiving a *copy* of `data`.  So any value the lambda assigns to its input parameter will be assigned to the copy and not reflected back to `data`.

You need to pass `data` *by reference* instead, eg:

```cpp
template<class T>
class Entity
{
public:
  Entity(std::function<void(T*&)> init, int idx) : index(idx)
  {
    init(data);
  }

  T* getData(){ return data; }

private:
  int index;
  T* data;
};
```

```cpp
Entity<Button> myEnt([](Button* &button){
  button = new Button();

  /* some complex, **unique**, initialization of button */

  }, 1);
```

Comment: A reference to a pointer is new to me, I must have missed reading up on that at some point, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize the pointer member, you need a reference or pointer to the member pointer, not the value of the pointer.

```
template<class T>
class entity
{
public:
  Entity(std::function<void(T**)> init, int idx) : index(idx)
  {
    init(&data);
  }

  T* getData(){ return data; }

Private:
  int index;
  T* data;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Entity<Button> myEnt([](Button** button){
  // you need a pointer to the pointer in order to initialize it
  *button = new Button();

  /* some complex, **unique**, initialization of button */

  }, 1);
```

Comment: That makes sense, in my example would the pointer have just been copied when passed into the lambda? Thanks

Comment: @jf192210 yes, in your example, the lambda is operating on a *copy* of the pointer